# Storybook create element

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I've strotybook and two component in it.
The first - botton.
The second - Header.
Let's look at these.

Component Button.
Here I added style for position.
I've two options for button, light and dark theme.
In dark option is all okay, but not for light option.

Here normal size for button and it has div block.
[image]

On next image button is on full window without div block.
different is here that I added decorator **(you can see it in component Button.story down).**

```js
Light.decorators = [ThemeDecorator('light_theme')];
```

But default option decorator **(you can see it in component Button.story down down).**

```js
decorators: [
        StyleDecorator,
        ThemeDecorator('dark_theme'), 
    ],
```

[image]

component Button.story

```js
    import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
    import cls from './Button.module.scss';
    import { Button } from './Button';
    import StyleDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/StyleDecorator/StyleDecorator';
    import ThemeDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/ThemeDecorator/ThemeDecorator';
    
    const meta = {
        title: 'widgets/Button', 
        component: Button,
        decorators: [
            StyleDecorator,
            ThemeDecorator('dark_theme'),
        ],
    } satisfies Meta<typeof Button>;
    
    export default meta;
    type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;
    
    export const Light: Story = {
        args: {
            children: 'test button',
            classname: cls.light_theme,
            style: { margin: '55px 0px 55px 15px' },
        },
    };
    
    Light.decorators = [ThemeDecorator('light_theme')]; // this option deleted dev block, why?
    
    export const Dark: Story = {
        args: {
            children: 'test button',
            classname: cls.dark_theme,
            style: { margin: '55px 0px 55px 15px' },
        },
    };
```

Let's look component Header.
Header containst inside some components, like NavBar, logotype and some yet.
Every component has file ****.module.scss.
How correct I can add these styles to Header.story.

```js
    import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
    import Header from './Header';
    import StyleDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/StyleDecorator/StyleDecorator';
    import ThemeDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/ThemeDecorator/ThemeDecorator';
    import BrowseRouteDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/BrowseRouteDecorator/BrowseRouteDecorator';
    import HeaderModuleDecorator from '../../../shared/config/storybook/HeaderModuleDecorator/HeaderModuleDecorator';
    
    // More on how to set up stories at: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction
    const meta = {
        title: 'page/Header', 
        component: Header,
        decorators: [
            StyleDecorator,
            ThemeDecorator('dark_theme'),
            BrowseRouteDecorator,
            HeaderModuleDecorator,
        ],
    } satisfies Meta<typeof Header>;
    
    export default meta;
    type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;
    
    // More on writing stories with args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args
    export const HeaderLight: Story = {
        args: {
        },
    };
    
    HeaderLight.decorators = [ThemeDecorator('light_theme')];
    
    export const HeaderDark: Story = {
        args: {
    
        },
    };
    // HeaderLight.decorators = [ThemeDecorator('dark_theme')];
```

Here I don't have style for button.
[image]

Here for light theme I don't have styles for all
[image]